# How to change the default icon as soon as page loads?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have this code to change my icon, but it only works when I click on it. How can I have the icon change as soon as the web page loads?

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: 'different_icon.png'});

});
```

Comment: As soon as which page loads? Any page the user browses to? Or are you loading your own HTML page in the extension? Please clarify.

Comment: Yup, I mean any page the user browses to, because I need to change the icon depending on which page user goes to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to pass a message to the background page and change the icon there. For example, your manifest file would have this content script:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches" : ["<all_urls>"],
        "js" : ["content.js"],
        "run_at": "document_end"
    }
],
```

As you can see, it runs when the document is done loading. Your content script passes a message to the background page:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({changeIcon: true});
```

And finally, your backgound page receives the message and changes the icon:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.changeIcon) {
            chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: 'different_icon.png'});
        }
    }
);
```